# Most General Definition of an L-Function

Tags: reference-request, l-functions

I have seen examples given of $L$-functions, such as Dirichlet $L$-functions and the Riemann Zeta Function, but I have not seen a definition of the most general form of an $L$-function. Basically what I am looking for a set of $L$-functions such that *all other L-functions*, including automorphic $L$-functions, are elements of that set. A reference to the defining characteristic of such a set would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is an open problem.  Try looking up "Selberg class" if you are only concerned with "classical" L-functions.  If you want to allow for p-adic L-functions, L-functions of graphs, etc, good luck!

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that difference. If you can post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the [Selberg class of L-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class).  This is an axiomatic definition of what we expect from all "reasonable" definitions of L-functions, but it's conjectural that this includes all standard constructions of (complex) L-functions from number theory.  On the other hand, Langlands' philosophy conjectures that all conventional L-functions coincide with automorphic L-functions.

Note that there are various other objects called "L-functions" or "zeta functions" outside of what I think of as conventional L/zeta functions from number theory---e.g., people study p-adic L-functions in number theory and various L-functions of graphs in graph theory.