# Definition of $L$-function of elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, l-functions

$L-$function *of elliptic curves* is Dirichlet series and defined to be $$
L(E,s) = \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{a_n}{n^s} = \prod_p L_p(E,s),
$$where the Euler factor at $p$ is
$$
L_p(E,s) = \begin{cases}(1-a_pp^{-s}+p\cdot p^{-2s})^{-1},&p\nmid N=N_E\\ (1\pm p^{-s})^{-1}
,&p||N\\ 1,& p^2|N,\end{cases}
$$
where $a_p=p+1-|E(F_p)|$.

Why is it defined this way?

We know Riemann zeta function, also a Dirichlet series, is
$\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^s}=\prod_{p \text{ prime}}(1-\frac1{p^s})^{-1}$. $L$-function *of elliptic curves* looks similar except for some p it has $\frac1{p^{2s}}$ in the denominator, why here is an extra term?

---

*Edits:*

**Zeta functions and L-functions are all *siblings, or possibly all analogs*, of Riemann zeta function.**
It seems one can get zeta/L-functions for a structure like a number field, a dynamical system, etc. by comparing the structure to number sets.

For example, Riemann zeta function equals $\sum \frac1{\text{(natural number)}^s}=\prod \frac1{1-\text{(norm, or absolute value, of prime number)}^{-s}}$.

Similarly for a number field (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}[i]$), since a field has a ring, we have algebraic integers ($\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$), and so we have ideals (subrings). The two examples here are principle ideal domain (PID), and so all their ideals are generated by an element $a$, i.e. the ideals are the smallest subring containing $a$, they are $aR$. These **ideals** behave like natural numbers. Since all PIDs are unique factorization domains (UFDs), we can define **prime ideals**, which behaves like primes except that 0 and 1 are included. And so we have a 'analog' of (for $\mathbb{Q}$, exactly) Riemann zeta function:

$\sum \frac1{\text{((principle) ideal)}^{2s}}=\prod \frac1{1-\text{(norm of prime ideal)}^{-2s}}$, where $2s$ is not fundamentally different from $s$. Note that more exactly it's *non zero* ideals and prime ideals.

The prime ideals, or simply primes, for Gaussian integers can be *derived* from the usual primes, namely

\begin{cases}
u_{-}^{+}iv, \text{where }u^2+v^2=4k+1, &p=4k+1\\
p, &p=4k+3\\
1_{-}^{+}i, \text{where the two primes gives the same prime ideal } (1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i], &p=2.
\end{cases}

The corresponding Euler factors are
$$\begin{cases}(1-2p^{-s}+ p^{-2s})^{-1}=(1-p^{-s})^{-1}(1-p^{-s})^{-1},\\
(1- p^{-2s})^{-1} =(1- (+p^{-s}))^{-1}(1-(- p^{-s}))^{-1}
,\\ (1- 2^{-s})^{-1},\end{cases}$$

Therefore zeta function for $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ is

$\prod_{p \text{ is a prime ideal}} \frac1{1-||p||^{-2s}} = (1-(\sqrt{2})^{-2s})(1-3^{-2s})(1-(\sqrt{5})^{-2s})(1-(\sqrt{5})^{-2s})\dots=(1-2^{-s})(1-3^{-2s})(1-(2)5^{-s}+5^{-2s})\dots$.

Write

1. $(1-p^{-s+1})$ for one of $(1-p^{-s})$, (*I don't know why but it seems to work and to fit the wiki link as mentioned in a comment,*)
2. $(1\pm p^{-s})^{-1}$ for $(1- p^{-2s})^{-1}$, (*since we are gonna do multiplication the two are the same,*)
3. $1$ for $(1- 2^{-s})^{-1}$, (*of this replacement I know no reason,*)

then we almost get L-funciton of *elliptic curves*, except we get $a_p=p+1$ instead of $a_p=p+1-|E(F_p)|$.

So we see here is indeed an analog between L-function of an *elliptic curve* and zeta-function of $\mathbb{Q}[i]$,

So

1. why we get a different $a_p$?
2. why there is an analog between L-function of an *elliptic curve* and zeta-function of $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ (NOT that of $\mathbb{Q}$). Does the reason have something to do with that an elliptic curve is sort of a 2-dim *torus* ($S^1\times S^1$), and $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ is 2-dim as well?

---

I add further discussion inspired by some comments @Mathmo123 in the comment-*chat*, basically I try to use matrix representation of projective transformation of a variety (mainly mobius transformation) and the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: It seems there are many L-functions. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3676606/577710, though I'm not sure how people get them. Riemann zeta function is also an example of L-function. My question may be better stated as why we can write a (or any) Dirichlet series/L-function as product of Euler factors like that in my quesion.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article [Hasse-Weil zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Weil_zeta_function)? It refers to a section of Silverman's book on elliptic curves.

Comment: I check the book. It’s a bit complicated and gives somehow different (though perhaps consistent) descriptions.

Comment: To turn the question on its head, why would you expect every $L$-function to look like the Riemann zeta function? The Riemann zeta function is a degree $1$ $L$-function, while the $L$-function attached to an elliptic curve is degree $2$. For me, the clearest explanation of this is that the Galois representation attached to an elliptic curve is $2$-dimensional, while the Galois representation attached to a Dirichlet character is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: So I guess though L-function or zeta functions are analogs of Riemann zeta functions, their behaviors should be similar in some aspects, they can be as different as R^2 from R^1, multivariate calculus from calculus of R to R functions.

Comment: As for the analogue with $\mathbb Q(i)$, there is a way to view a degree $1$ $L$-function over $\mathbb Q(i)$ as a degree $2$ $L$-function over $\mathbb Q$. For elliptic curves specifically, if you take an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ with CM by an imaginary quadratic field $K$, then its $L$-function over $\mathbb Q$ is actually equal to the $L$ function of a Hecke character over $K$.

Comment: From here https://www.lmfdb.org/L/degree2/ I know Riemann zeta function is L-function of degree 1, and L-function of elliptic curve is of degree 2. For all degrees, the Euler product has two parts, one for p that divides N, one for p that doesn't;  $a_p$ is usually the coefficient for $p^{-s}$ term for Euler product;while $\mathcal{X}$ (corresponding to p here) is the character for $p^{-ks}$, and sometimes $p^{-(k-1)s}$, (for p divides N), where k is the degree. Such are conclusions. But I'm wondering how people get these formulae and why L-function of elliptic curve is of degree 2.

Comment: About the equivalence between L-function of elliptic curve over Q with Complex Multiplicaiton (degree 2?) and L-function of a Hecke character (degree 1?), I'm not quite sure what the former is, I guess you refer to an L-function of differential geometric origin, and it is equal to an L-function of arithmetic origin? Or both are L-functions of arithmetic origin and they are equivalent because by manipulating their formulae?

Comment: If you have a Galois representation $\rho: G_\mathbb Q\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$, for each prime $p$, define $f_p$ to be the characteristic polynomial of the Frobenius element $\mathrm{Frob}_p$ acting on $V^{I_p}$, the elements of $V$ fixed by inertia. We then define the local factor $L_p(s)$ to be $f_p(p^{-s})^{-1}$. When $p\nmid N$, $I_p$ acts trivially, so the degree of $f_p$ is equal to the degree of $V$. Conversely, if $p\mid N$, $I_p$ will not act trivially, leading to a polynomial of smaller dimension. There are of course other ways to derive these formula without using Galois representations.

Comment: So Frobenius element acting on $V^{I_p}$ (elements of $V$ invariant under $I_p$) will give a matrix $M$ (whose rank is degree $d$ of the variety $V$ (similar to dimension of a manifold) or $d-1$, and equal to degree of $L$-function or that minus $1$). When $p \nmid N$, $M=\left[\begin{array}{l l} 1 &0\\ 0 &1\end{array}\right]$, and characteristic polynomial of $\text{Frob}_p$ acting on $V^{I_p}$ will be that of $M$, i.e. $(1-x)^2$, and so the local/Euler factor will be $(1-p^{-s})^2$ (corresponding to 'p=4k+1');

Comment: when $p | N$, $M$ will degenerate to $[1]$ or $[\pm 1]$, and so the characteristic polynomial will be $(1-x), (\pm 1-x)$ (corresponding to 'p=2, 4k+3'), and so we get the $L$-function.

Comment: My question is that how we get the characteristic polynomial $\Phi$, or the matrix $M$, from https://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/jahnel/Arbeiten/weilpol2c.pdf we see $\Phi$ is just a polynomial with rational coefficients (i.e. $M$'s entries are rational), but from that it seems $\Phi$ can be an arbitrary such polynomial. I said above that $M$ is possibly $\left[\begin{array}{l l} 1 &0\\ 0 &1\end{array}\right]$, etc, but that's just my guessing; **it seems both $\text{Frob}_p$ and $V^{I_p}$ affect $M$, but I don't know how**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112572/discussion-between-charlie-chang-and-mathmo123).